# How to Flag least recent as duplicate data where detail name can be exchanged with unwanted literals and same sound?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a table where I want to find customer duplicate records in a bucket , migrate recent one and flag rest to duplicates.

It seems simple right, but here comes the tricky part..
Sometime FirstName is as LastName and viceversa.

```
Use Tempdb
Go
Declare @customer table (Id int, FirstName varchar(50), LastName Varchar(50),Isdup bit)

Insert into @customer(id,FirstName,LastName)
Select 1,'Harry','Potter'
Union All
Select 2,'Harry','Potter'
Union All
Select 3,'Potter','Harry'
Union All
Select 4,'Potter','Harry'
Union All
Select 5,'Dumbeldore','Albert'
Union All
Select 6,,'Dumbeldore','Albert'
Union All
Select 7,'Albert','Dumbeldore'
Union All
Select 8,'Albert','Dumbldore'
Union All
Select 9,'Albert','Dumbel-dore'
```

Question: Would like get recent duplicate data flag as 0 and rest as 1.

Any leads are welcome ☺️.

Comment: How would you know that the names are reversed? This seems awfully brittle to me. How do you know that Christopher Lloyd and Lloyd Christopher are in fact the same person. Maybe they aren't the same person.

Comment: That I don't need to care about , we'll put rest it in duplicate bucket and provide interface if app user want to merge it delete it or add as new

Comment: @Sean was it was a typo , posting from Android is a real mess specially with formatting, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standardize the comparison value by putting the "lesser" of the two names first and the "greater" of the two names second, then run the rest of your logic off of that new field.

The logic is simple...

```
    select case when FirstName < LastName then FirstName + LastName else LastName + FirstName end as StandardName from Whatever
```

That turns every "Harry Potter" and "Potter Harry" into "HarryPotter".
And it turns every "Albert Dumbledore" and "Dumbledore Albert" into "AlbertDumbledore".

From there, it sounds like you'd have a handle on de-duping.

Comment: In addition to this, is  there any regex function we can use to remove unwanted literals and then standardize same?

Comment: @HarsimranjeetSingh you were already merging two questions and now are adding a third.  This question was already at risk of being down-voted for that reason.  Regex (well documented at stack and elsewhere) can be applied to the merged StandardName field to whatever extent necessary and the logic can flow downstream from that.

Comment: I'm quite impressed with that trick and appreciate it, but how if there's were literals in it or same sounding name, I know about Soundex function but that hardly appropriate sometimes ?

Comment: @HarsimranjeetSingh Are you suggesting that in addition to First and Last Names being reversed sometimes, there may also be multiple spellings or use of punctuation?  If so, then standardize the name as described above and apply new operations to it as needed, researching here and elsewhere, and posting a separate question after you have thoroughly ruled out existing answers (I doubt you're trying to do anything that stack doesn't already cover)/

Comment: this a single question with probability of data that can be there as dup.